# Adding separators between letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, separator

I have the following HTML to give ABC links for a long list of items divided into pages by letter of the alphabet. I cannot change the HTML.

```
<p>
    <a href="A.html">A</a>

    <!-- all the items on this page start with this letter 
         It is not contained in any special div, just floats among the links -->
    B

    <a href="c.html">C</a>        
    <a href="d.html">D</a>        
    <a href="e.html">E</a>        
    <a href="f.html">F</a>        
    <a href="g.html">G</a>

    <!-- and so on through z -->
</p>
```

I need to put a separator (the following HTML) between every letter:

```
<span class="separator">|</span>
```

However, if I put a separator before or after every link, the plain letter will not have a separator between itself and one of the links surrounding it.

How can I place a separator between every link, without changing the HTML, keeping in mind that any of the letters can be plain text without a containing `<a>` or any other tag except for the outer `<p>`?

**Edited** to show desired results (two of many possibilities). The letter in bold is not a link; all the other letters are:

**A** | B | C | D | E | F ...

A | B | **C** | D | E | F ...

Comment: how about adding it in CSS? `p > a{border-left:1px solid black;} p > a:first-child{border-left:none;}`

Comment: @daniel: how will this help with the letter not contained in the `<a>`?

Comment: I couldn't quite wrap my head around how you wanted plain letters to appear on the page - also with a seperator? - if that's the case you could use lettering.js->http://letteringjs.com/

Comment: Seeing your edit - letteringjs is definitely an option that would also give you 'powerful' css control over the plain text - (in short: calling the lettering function on the `p` would automatically wrap all the plain text letters in `<span>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var separator = "<span class='separator'>|</span>";

$("p").contents().each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($.trim($this.text()).length>0){
        if(this.nodeType == 3){
            // text node, possibly multiple characters that need separation
            var characters = this.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, "").split("");
            var output = "";

            for(var i=0; i<characters.length; i++){
                output += " " + characters[i] + separator;
            }                    

            $(this).replaceWith(output + " ");                
        } else {
            $this.after(separator);
        }
    }
});

$(".separator:last").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kJ3yW/1/

Comment: Updated to handle the possibility that there are 2 consecutive non-linked characters.

Comment: very smart to consider that possibility. Thanks!

Comment: One problem: I need to add in not just | but <span class="separator">|</span>

Comment: Thank you! One more thing- the last `<span class="separator">|</span>`, after the Z, has to be removed.

Comment: Got it- added `$("span.separator:last").remove();` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var p = // some method of getting the correct <p> tag
var c = p.childNodes, i, isfirst = true, s;
for(i=0;i<c.length;i++) { // skip the first child node
  if( c[i].tagName || c[i].nodeValue.match(/[a-z]/)) {
    // if node is a tag or a non-empty text node
    if( isfirst) isfirst = false; // skip first node
    else {
      s = p.insertBefore(document.createElement('span'),c[i]);
      s.className = "separator";
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode("|"));
      i++; // IMPORTANT! Adding a node requires us to manually iterate forward one step!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When using `var p = $(".abcLinks p")` to get the correct paragraph, p.childNodes is undefined.

Comment: And if I use `p.contents()` instead of p.childNodes, `s.appendChild(...)` returns the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'**

Comment: Don't use jQuery, it's more trouble than it's worth.